# Can we play to reach study like positions?

Tags: study

I am talking about a field called "Chess Study". A typical chess study is very complex, and even computers make mistakes in solving them.

So, can we play some variation which can result in such positions ?

See for example this very famous study and its commentary:

[Solution to a truly remarkable study](https://en.chessbase.com/post/solution-to-a-truly-remarkable-study)

[Grandmasters and Engines Couldn't Solve This Puzzle. Then Came The Magician](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wCJalNkTEI&t=564s)

Answer (score 2):

> So, can we play some variation which can result in such positions ?

If a study is legal, so can be reached from the starting position by a series of legal moves, then the answer to your question is trivially "Yes".

Chess players shouldn't really collude before the game to decide the outcome but when siblings or partners play each other they sometimes play an agreed sequence of moves which leads to a forced draw.

In the same way two players could work out the moves required to reach a particular study position, agree to play them and then play them.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about collusion, but is wanting to play an opening where the opponent *might* play moves that would lead to a study position of some sort.

Comment: @DM Many endgame studies could arise from almost any opening. Hence the answer is still, trivially, yes. Although the chances of reaching any particular study position are very small. The chances of reaching any study-like position during any game are obviously much higher.